# Abaqus: Creating a new FieldOutput (format?)

Tags: python, abaqus

Been struggling with following: I want to create a new FieldOutput (lets say some simple aritmetic operation with the tensors) for a given el. set. Not the whole model as this would be too costly and Im interested in that particular area/set anyway.

I open an odb with the results....

```
from abaqus import *
from odbAccess import *
from abaqusConstants import *
import visualization
import fileinput
import os

# to make prettyPrint work!
from odbAccess import *
from textRepr import *

# open odb
odb_path="analysis45.odb"
my_odb=session.openOdb(name=odb_path,readOnly=FALSE)
```

Some substitutions that assure that it always opens the step/instance no matter what their name is...

```
# automate the proces of reading the step no matter what its name is
StepNames=(my_odb.steps.keys() )        #   it is a list of all step names
lastStep=( StepNames[-1] )  

# automation of an instance naming (in the same way)
NaseInstance = (my_odb.rootAssembly.instances.keys())
MojeInstance = ( NaseInstance[-1] ) 
CelaMojeInstance=my_odb.rootAssembly.instances[MojeInstance]
```

Found somebody elses way to calculate new data and stuff them into a new scalar here: https://gist.github.com/crmccreary/5015483 I am, though, not successful in understanding what exactly happens there as this script is much more complicated and Im not a programmer at all.

Tried to simplify the task by hard-prescribing some value directly to the field (with the intention to replace this by a function later on and finally to loop over the whole elset this way). Im getting a message regarding **"illegal argument type for built-in operation"** form which I assume that the format of the data Im trying to insert is not correct. Tried the documentation w/o success. May I ask for a hint/help? Thanks!

```
NewField =my_odb.steps[lastStep].frames[0].FieldOutput(name='New_scalar_field',description='Our brand new scalar field', type=SCALAR)
NewField.addData(position=NODAL, instance=CelaMojeInstance, labels=[1657, 1658, 1683, 1684, 14193, 14194, 14195, 14196], data=[(6),(12),(6),(12),(6),(12),(6),(12)])

my_odb.save()
my_odb.close()
```

This guys solution seems to be quite the same to the mine: http://abaqus-users.1086179.n5.nabble.com/Writing-Results-to-Existing-ODB-file-td21750.html

I understand that the question may be too trivial or too silly for seniors, sorry about that.

Comment: Trust me, nobody who scripts abaqus will disagree about unclear documentation.  Have you tried taking the parentheses out of `data`?

Comment: Hi! Thanks. I have actually added the parentheses there later as the guy from the link uses them. No difference.

Comment: Have you ried a list of floats instead?  i.e `[12.,6., . . . .]`

Comment: Yes, I came to the same idea a little while ago. Still the same outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason it works when I type:

```
data=[(6.0,),(12.0,),(6.0,),(12.0,),(6.0,),(12.0,),(6.0,),(12.0,)]
```

with the commas after the values. I dont really know why. Hopefully it helps somebody else in the future.

Comment: It wants a list of 1-tuples then.  Probably because if you had `type=VECTOR` you'd need a 3-tuple for every point.

Comment: The strange thing is that all the other (few) examples that I found out there on the internet did not need this. Dont know whether it is a question of version (which seems improbable to me) or what else... I have just checked by picking probes in GUI that the values in the nodes are really these twelves and sixes from up above.

Comment: good find. You should add your version info for future reference.

Comment: Sure. 6.14-2 if it really is of any importance

Comment: this behavior is per documentation ( "data":"A sequence of sequences of Floats"). The comma makes it a length-one sequence. I looked at v6.9 and 6.14 docs and they are worded the same, so its a bit of mystery why the linked example evidently worked.

Answer (score -1):

The data must be consist of a tuple of tuples, just like this:

```
((1,),(2,),(3,)).
```

Your data is consists of a tuple of numbers, like this: `((1),(2),(3))`. In python, `(1) == 1`. It's just parenthesis. To make a tuple with one element use a comma `(1,) != 1`.

I have met the same question as you, and I have fixed it this way.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).